# find positions where vector decreases

Tags: r, vector

x<-c(2 ,**1**, 3 ,**1**, 3, 4)

The vector here decreases at two places. This is just an example vector. Here at second position and at 4rth position the vector decreases(from 2 to 1 and from 3 to 1) . I want to find these positions

Comment: `which(sign(diff(x)) == -1) + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that by simply comparing the vector to itself with a shift:

```
x < c(0,x[-length(x)])
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

where you shift `x` by one value (introducing the `0` and ignoring the last value of `x`, `length(x)`).

To find which positions are decreasing you can use `which` on that logical vector:

```
which(x < c(0,x[-length(x)]))
[1] 2 4
```